# viewWIllTransition is not getting called in more than one Controller

Tags: ios, swift, viewwilltransitiontosize

I am learning to develop iOS application and currently i have 4 view controllers.

In the **first viewController** i have used the method **viewWillTransition** to adjust UI at the runtime.

Again in the **4th ViewController** i am trying to use the method **viewWillTransition**, but it is not getting called there.

And when i did comment the method (viewWillTransition) in **first controller** it magically started to be working in **fourth viewController**. So i came to the conclusion that **viewWillTransition** can only be implemented in only one viewController But i need to use it in multiple places.

What is the work around ? How can i fix it ?
I am using Swift4 and Xcode9.

Comment: did you call `super` on `viewWillTransition(to: with:)`? The first line of your method implementation should be `super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)`

Comment: No. Thankyou so much sam :). I was calling the super only at one place..

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: like a charm... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just reposting my comment as an answer,

You must call `super` somewhere in the implementation of your `viewWillTransition(to: with:)`. Usually it is the first line.

It should look something like this:

```
super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
```

This will allow the superview to pass this method class to all of its subviews. So if you have a `UIViewController` inside a `UITabBarController`, calling this method on super will allow all the other tabs to receive this method call.

Answer (score 0):

Also -- If using a custom containerViewController with child viewControllers?

If you have added a child viewController's view to a parent viewController as a subview you must call the `.addChild(_:)` method on the parent viewController to create the parent-child relationship between the two view controllers.